# pydrake controller with ros-gazebo

Tags: python, drake

**Background:** I have a rospy-gazebo implementation of a robot simulator. I'm currently using ros_control to collect state estimation data and control joints through a position controller at each joint. I'm interested in transitioning to using the more mature controller types that drake offers.

My current plan is to execute "low-level" torque control at each joint via my current interface of ros_control, but additionally I am interested in creating a pydrake controller (for example PID, or LQR) that:

- accepts state estimate (e.g. joint position and velocity vectors)
- returns a torque command (which will then get published to the torque controller topic).

**Tried so far:** I've searched a fair bit through both the [documentation](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.systems.controllers.html#pydrake.systems.controllers.MakeFiniteHorizonLinearQuadraticRegulator), [examples](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/bindings/pydrake/examples/multibody), [tutorials](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/tutorials) as well as the [*underactuated* course notes](http://underactuated.mit.edu/index.html), [associated collab jupyter note books](http://underactuated.mit.edu/lqr.html#example2), and [drake-ros notes](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-ros/tree/develop) but am not able to find an example. In particular it appears that most of the examples are using the *simulator* object, native to drake, as opposed to creating a controller and then calling the controller "standalone" from within a different simulation environment (in this case ros-gazebo).

**Question:** If anyone knows of an example that does what I'm describing (i.e. instantiating a controller, then calling it with the current state at each time step), I'd be grateful to be pointed to said example. If such a thing doesn't exist, I'd be happy with a little guidance on how to achieve what I've described.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: were you able to achieve this ? , I am trying to achieve something similar